# 3W LED light (15x 3w LED)

Tags: led

I've started to play with LEDs but every time I feel I've come to understand them, I get confused again... I have attached my plan so far, I was wondering if any of you could give me some advice!

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say but your question isn't going to be received well. It is not clear what you are asking , and there is no way to give an exact answer. I recommend you read the site help or FAQ or check other good questions, maybe of similar topic as yours, as an example.

Comment: The power supply is not clear. Says current source but marked 18V. Basically you have all of your LEDs connected in parallel. Don't know about the power supply spec. but if not limited consider the following: Let us say the drop across a RED LED is a pessimistic 2.2V so you'll have (18-2.2) / 4.7 = 3.36 A into the LED. That is more than twice the wattage you are after.

Comment: Is that a constant voltage or constant current source?

Answer (score 1):

**IF** your supply was a 6V voltage source (and NOT a current source as shown) then it would produce LEDs of approximately 700 mA drive each **AND** a lot of heat.

You will have an easier time if you start with a few LEDs only - say one of each colour initially. The extras add complexity and do not add much in initial understanding. And it would be useful if you explain what you are trying to achieve, other than make lots of light.

Assume to start that the voltage drops for each LED are exactly the average of the range of Vfs shown (eg red = 2.2-2.8V so assume 2.6V Vf).
So string voltage at 700 ma = 0.7A current =
Vf_average + I_LED x R_series.

Vred = 2.5V + 0.7 x 4.7 =  5.79V
Vblue = 3.65 + 0.7 x 3.3 = 5.96V
Vdeep_red = 2.4 x 0.7 x 4.7 = 5.69V

So all LED strings "expect" about a 6V  supply to operate correctly.
If you placed the 3 strings in seriES you would need ABOUT 18v to povide 700 mA down the whole string, so this MAY explain why you show an "18V current source" - which is a confused concept in this context.

As the deep-red string needs slightly less than 6V to draw 700 ma it will draw MORE than 700 mA when 6V is applied.  The red string will draw slightly more (as Vstring = 5.79V , and the blue string almost exactly 700mA.

However, the assumption was made that all LEDs had a Vf of the average for the type of LED concerned.In practice individual LED will vary in Vf. Depending on the matching of the LEDs used there will be variations in Vf per LED so variations in current per LED. To drive LEDs in a group equally they must all be driven by current sources or all must be in series. By adding series resistors you are approximating current sources but wasting more than half your input power as heat. By placing a number of LEDs in series and using a single resistor per series string you can reduce the wasted power in resistors.

More information can be provided depending on how you deal with the above.